# Redirecting to non-symlinked virtual host directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Currently I arrange my /var/www directory with each site in its own folder named after the hostname (e.g. /var/www/www.example.com). When I want to also cater for the non-www version (or something else) I just symlink to the proper directory (so /var/www/example.com symlinks to /var/www/www.example.com).

I want to take this a step further and have apache do a permanent redirect to the non-symlinked directory. I've come up with the following RewriteMap perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1;
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    if (-l "/var/www/$_") {
        print readlink . "\n";
    } else {
        print "NULL\n";
    }
}
```

I've never perled before so forgive any errors. I've tested it and it works well and conforms to the spec.

The hard part is the actual rewrite rules. I've tried this and it's as far as I've got. I'm suspecting that I need to have a condition that checks if there is a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so in the process of writing this question I figured out a few things.

Firstly one needs to supply a newline character after NULL from whatever script you're running. I've put that in the question. We then check if the match isn't an empty string and proceed from there:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0

RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap symlinks prg:/var/www/redirector.pl
RewriteCond ${symlinks:%{HTTP_HOST}} !=""
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://${symlinks:%{HTTP_HOST}}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My solution ignores SSL but it's likely that you'll override the default catchall virtual host for your SSL sites to add key's etc...